# xpra ubuntu html5 server problems

Tags: ubuntu, web, xpra

I have installed xpra from the ubuntu repos (16.10). I also have installed websockify.  When I try to use it to set up an html5 session with the following:

```
xpra start --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:14500 --html=on --start-child=xterm
```

I get the following error:

```
xpra initialization error:
 failed to setup websockify html server: cannot find xpra's html directory
 (not found in '/usr/share/xpra/www')
```

and I am currently stuck. Any suggestions?

I am attempting to make xpra provide X applications remotely over the web, using Ubuntu (16.10). This should be easy from everything I have read.

Comment: Which version of xpra? From which repo? Try the packages from xpra.org instead.

Comment: I did, and it worked. As I said, it was xpra from the Ubuntu 16.10 repo. It apparently was missing some dependencies.

Comment: I had similar issues with the Ubuntu 18.04 prepackaged binary.  Switching to xpra.org's repo solved the issue for me.